# Can't stream AAC file with HTML5 on iOS Safari

Tags: mobile-safari, html5-audio, aac, m3u

I'm trying to embed this stream in to an HTML5 `audio` tag to be targeted at iOS mobile safari users: http://cjzn.streamon.fm/listen.m3u

After searching around I discovered that you can't embed M3U files directly with an HTML5 audio tag. So I saved that M3U file and opened it up, and it's only contents were:
`http://cjzn.streamon.fm:8000/CJZN-48k.aac?starttime=1372879409`

My next logical step was to try and embed that AAC file in to the audio tag, like so:
`<audio src="http://cjzn.streamon.fm:8000/CJZN-48k.aac", autoplay="true"></audio>`

But I still can't seem to get it working. Can anyone help me out?

As well, taking a step back to the M3U file - would it be smarter to try and use an M3U parser and convert the file in to a playlist that an audio player like jPlayer could play? What's the best option for me here? All I want to do is embed this stream in to my mobile Safari app.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment AAC+ giving headache when it comes to Flash and HTML5. But actually you can link your M3U file from your Safari web app.

Steps -

- Just create M3U file and upload it to your web server.
- Then put a HTML link to that M3U file.
- Example : `<a href="playlist.m3u'>Play Stream</a>`

All Apple devices will play that stream. I checked mine with Ipad, Iphone and Ipod touch.

I hope this will help you. Good luck !